# Go scheduler and CGO: Please explain this difference of behavior?

Tags: go, scheduler

I'd like to know the implementation reason for this:

```
package main

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        print("a")
        for {
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        print("b")
        for {
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        print("c")
        c <- struct{}{}
        for {
        }
    }()

    <-c
}

❯❯❯ GOMAXPROCS=2 go run sample1.go                                    
ab  <--- blocks.
```

---

```
package main

// static void loop() { for(;;); }
import "C"

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        print("a")
        C.loop()
        print("x")
    }()

    go func() {
        print("b")
        C.loop()
        print("y")
    }()

    go func() {
        print("c")
        c <- struct{}{}
        C.loop()
        print("z")
    }()

    <-c
}

❯❯❯ GOMAXPROCS=2 go run sample2.go                                    
abc  <--- ends gracefully.
```

More specifically I mean how the C tight loop differs from the Go one in the context of go routine scheduling. And even though the C tight loops should be being abruptly terminated at the end of the Go program, I'd like to know whether it's safe to rely on this behavior to start C tasks without blocking the Go program.

Comment: The C compiler probably optimizes the empty loop away.

Comment: @Arjan: that's incorrect

Comment: @Arjan yes, output also supports it's incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime can't preempt a true busy-loop. A CPU intensive loop with no scheduling points has to be in it's own thread for other goroutines to be able to run. Function calls and channel send or receive operations all yield. Network IO is scheduled asynchronously, and file IO gets its own thread.

Generally setting `GOMAXPROCS` > 1 is sufficient, but since you have 3 of these loops, and only 2 threads, the scheduler is still blocked. If you have a valid CPU intensive loop that is making it difficult to schedule goroutines, you can call `runtime.GoSched()` periodically to yield to the scheduler. In the real world, the only place where this generally maters is a programming error where you have an empty loop.

All cgo calls happen in their own threads outside of the go runtime, so those loops have no effect on the main loop, other than wasting CPU.

Comment: The sentence "It has to be in it's own thread for other goroutines to be scheduled" is not very clear IMO. The busy loop has to be in its own thread, and because of this the others can be scheduled?

Comment: @pepper_chico: tried to fix the wording a bit. Although goroutines are scheduled automatically, they are in a sense still cooperative. If there's no free threads to run a goroutine, and the running goroutine[s] aren't yielding, there's no way to continue.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I think it would just better if you worded that the loop requires its own thread which implies >1 (GOMAXPROCS) are necessary to be enabled for the scheduler to run the other ones.

Comment: send and receive operations in a Go busy loop are not scheduling points? I thought net IO (send/receive?) would be so.

Comment: send and receive are channel operations, and they  *are* scheduling points. Net IO also yields to a scheduler, but there's no way to create a busy loop around that, you have a function call boundary and the blocking call itself. File IO happens in separate threads, not limited by `GOMAXPROCS`. In the real world, the only place where this generally maters is a programming error where you have an empty loop.

Comment: Hence I asked, your wording seem to imply that "(function calls, send or receive operations)" are example of A: CPU intensive loop with no scheduling points, B: example of scheduling points. From your comment I see you mean the last, except that I didn't expect plain function calls are subject to the go scheduler (which seems what you meant assuming function calls are example of scheduling points).